# My Erlang application don't see ranch module dependency

Tags: erlang, rebar, ranch

(Newbie here) I am having an error when trying to run [ranch example](https://github.com/ninenines/ranch/tree/master/examples/tcp_reverse).
Via `rebar` I created application and node (please see on [github](https://github.com/dima-starosud/ranch-test)).
But when I am trying to build and run it I am getting `undef` `ranch,start_listener`.

Please see full console output:

```
$ rebar get-deps compile generate && sh rel/reverse/bin/reverse console
WARN:  Expected reverse/deps/ranch to be an app dir (containing ebin/*.app), but no .app found.
==> rel (get-deps)
==> reverse (get-deps)
WARN:  Expected reverse/deps/ranch to be an app dir (containing ebin/*.app), but no .app found.
Pulling ranch from {git,"git@github.com:ninenines/ranch.git",{tag,"1.1.0"}}
Cloning into 'ranch'...
==> ranch (get-deps)
==> ranch (compile)
Compiled src/ranch_transport.erl
Compiled src/ranch_sup.erl
Compiled src/ranch_ssl.erl
Compiled src/ranch_tcp.erl
Compiled src/ranch_protocol.erl
Compiled src/ranch_listener_sup.erl
Compiled src/ranch_app.erl
Compiled src/ranch_acceptors_sup.erl
Compiled src/ranch_acceptor.erl
Compiled src/ranch_server.erl
Compiled src/ranch.erl
Compiled src/ranch_conns_sup.erl
==> rel (compile)
==> reverse (compile)
Compiled src/reverse_sup.erl
Compiled src/reverse_app.erl
Compiled src/reverse_protocol.erl
==> rel (generate)
WARN:  'generate' command does not apply to directory reverse
Exec: reverse/rel/reverse/erts-6.3/bin/erlexec  -boot reverse/rel/reverse/releases/1/reverse -mode embedded -config reverse/rel/reverse/releases/1/sys.config -args_file reverse/rel/reverse/releases/1/vm.args -- console
Root: reverse/rel/reverse
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3] [source-f9282c6] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.3  (abort with ^G)
(reverse@127.0.0.1)1> 
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Dec-2014::22:47:08 ===
    application: reverse
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{reverse_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {undef,
                         [{ranch,start_listener,
                              [reverse,10,ranch_tcp,
                               [{port,5555}],
                               reverse_protocol,[]],
                              []},
                          {reverse_app,start,2,
                              [{file,"src/reverse_app.erl"},{line,13}]},
                          {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                              [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                               {line,272}]}]}}}}
    type: permanent
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,reverse,{bad_return,{{reverse_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{ranch,start_listener,[reverse,10,ranch_tcp,[{port,5555}],reverse_protocol,[]],[]},{reverse_app,start,2,[{file,\"src/reverse_app.erl\"},{line,13}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,\"application_master.erl\"},{line,272}]}]}}}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
```

I am not sure I correctly added `ranch` to `reltool.config` ([please see on github](https://github.com/dima-starosud/ranch-test/blob/master/rel/reltool.config#L27)). But If I remove `deps` from `libs_dir` path I will get `rebar generate` error `Application version clash. Multiple directories contain version ...`.

**UPDATE** if I remove [failing call](https://github.com/dima-starosud/ranch-test/blob/master/src/reverse_app.erl#L13) and run it, `application:which_applications().` gives me `{ranch,[],[]}` as one of the running ones.

**UPDATE** versions

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3] [source-f9282c6] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

$ rebar --version
rebar 2.5.1 17 20141223_141030 git 2.5.1-84-gdd9125e
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `reltool.config`, remove the `ebin` directory from the path to Ranch:

```
{app, ranch, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}, {lib_dir, "../deps/ranch/"}]}
```

If you have lots of dependencies it's more convenient to do:

```
{lib_dirs, ["../deps"]}
```

instead of having a separate `{app, <dep_name>, [...]}` for each dependency.

The `Application version clash. Multiple directories contain version XXX` error indicates that the Ranch application is already installed, probably in the Erlang lib directory, creating conflicts with the deps version downloaded by Rebar.

Comment: Removing `deps` gives me `Application version clash` error as I wrote in the question.

Comment: If I completely remove `{app, ranch, [...]}` and add `{lib_dirs, ["../deps"]}` instead I get `{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot load',ranch_sup,get_files}}`.

Comment: I cloned your repo and tried my `{app, ranch, ...}` patch, works fine for me. Also removing that line and doing `{lib_dirs, ["../deps"]}` works as expected.

Comment: Looks good :) Now let us figure out the difference between our environments. Which versions of Erlang and rebar are you using? (I added version info into question)

Comment: R17 + Rebar 2.1.0. Have you installed Ranch manually somewhere else? sounds like rebar finds multiple versions of it.

Comment: Strange, probably this is an issue. I looked for `ranch` in my machine and found: `/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ranch-1.0.1`.

Should I delete it?

Comment: Yes, remove it, that's likely the problem.

Comment: If you download the Erlang Solutions Enterprise package, it includes ranch and other applications in the system erlang lib directory.